# Split String Into Array Elements Based On Punctuation In String - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, object

I want to split a string into separate array elements *by sentence*. So a split needs to occur after every period.

I.e. this:

```
Love is a burning thing and it makes a fiery ring.
Bound by wild desire, I fell in to a ring of fire.
```

Will become this:

```
[ 'Love is a burning thing and it makes a fiery ring.',
 'Bound by wild desire, I fell into a ring of fire', ]
```

`Array[0]` in this case will be `"Love is a burning thing and it makes a fiery ring."`.

I tried this:

```
function splitLyrics(string) {
  let newArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    let character = string[i];
    let sentence = "";

    if (character !== ".") {
      sentence.concat(character);
    }

    newArray.push(sentence);

  }

  return newArray;

}

console.log(splitLyrics("Love is a burning thing and it makes a fiery ring. Bound by wild desire, I fell in to a ring of fire."));
```

And as you can see, my problem is that I don't know how to combine the individual character elements into sentence elements, separated by when there's a period.

What functions are out there that could achieve what I'm looking for, following my existing logic?

https://www.codewars.com/kata/99-bottles-of-beer-1/train/javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use a regular expression and `.match` instead - match a non-space character, followed by non-period characters, followed by a period character:

```js
const splitLyrics = str => str.match(/\S[^.]*\./g);

console.log(splitLyrics("Love is a burning thing and it makes a fiery ring. Bound by wild desire, I fell in to a ring of fire."));
```

This is easily extendible to other sentence-terminating punctuation too, like exclamation and question marks:

```js
const splitLyrics = str => str.match(/\S[^.?!]*[.?!]/g);

console.log(splitLyrics("Love is a burning thing and it makes a fiery ring. Bound by wild desire, I fell in to a ring of fire. Foo bar! Bar baz? Buzz."));
```

If `var song = sing();` is required, and the tester proceeds to call `song`, then you should write a function that *returns* a function, though this seems like a very odd thing to do:

```js
const sing = () => str => str.match(/\S[^.]*\./g);
const song = sing();
console.log(song("Love is a burning thing and it makes a fiery ring. Bound by wild desire, I fell in to a ring of fire."));
```

It appears that the kata is expecting you to paste in the entire lyrics for the song and then return the appropriate line:

> You can find the complete lyrics here.

So either do that:

```js
// snippet isn't actually runnable, but it's too much text to paste in the answer proper

const sing = () => `99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 98 bottles of beer on the wall.

98 bottles of beer on the wall, 98 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 97 bottles of beer on the wall.

97 bottles of beer on the wall, 97 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 96 bottles of beer on the wall.

96 bottles of beer on the wall, 96 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 95 bottles of beer on the wall.

95 bottles of beer on the wall, 95 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 94 bottles of beer on the wall.

94 bottles of beer on the wall, 94 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 93 bottles of beer on the wall.

93 bottles of beer on the wall, 93 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 92 bottles of beer on the wall.

92 bottles of beer on the wall, 92 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 91 bottles of beer on the wall.

91 bottles of beer on the wall, 91 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 90 bottles of beer on the wall.

90 bottles of beer on the wall, 90 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 89 bottles of beer on the wall.

89 bottles of beer on the wall, 89 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 88 bottles of beer on the wall.

88 bottles of beer on the wall, 88 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 87 bottles of beer on the wall.

87 bottles of beer on the wall, 87 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 86 bottles of beer on the wall.

86 bottles of beer on the wall, 86 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 85 bottles of beer on the wall.

85 bottles of beer on the wall, 85 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 84 bottles of beer on the wall.

84 bottles of beer on the wall, 84 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 83 bottles of beer on the wall.

83 bottles of beer on the wall, 83 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 82 bottles of beer on the wall.

82 bottles of beer on the wall, 82 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 81 bottles of beer on the wall.

81 bottles of beer on the wall, 81 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 80 bottles of beer on the wall.

80 bottles of beer on the wall, 80 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 79 bottles of beer on the wall.

79 bottles of beer on the wall, 79 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 78 bottles of beer on the wall.

78 bottles of beer on the wall, 78 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 77 bottles of beer on the wall.

77 bottles of beer on the wall, 77 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 76 bottles of beer on the wall.

76 bottles of beer on the wall, 76 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 75 bottles of beer on the wall.

75 bottles of beer on the wall, 75 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 74 bottles of beer on the wall.

74 bottles of beer on the wall, 74 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 73 bottles of beer on the wall.

73 bottles of beer on the wall, 73 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 72 bottles of beer on the wall.

72 bottles of beer on the wall, 72 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 71 bottles of beer on the wall.

71 bottles of beer on the wall, 71 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 70 bottles of beer on the wall.

70 bottles of beer on the wall, 70 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 69 bottles of beer on the wall.

69 bottles of beer on the wall, 69 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 68 bottles of beer on the wall.

68 bottles of beer on the wall, 68 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 67 bottles of beer on the wall.

67 bottles of beer on the wall, 67 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 66 bottles of beer on the wall.

66 bottles of beer on the wall, 66 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 65 bottles of beer on the wall.

65 bottles of beer on the wall, 65 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 64 bottles of beer on the wall.

64 bottles of beer on the wall, 64 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 63 bottles of beer on the wall.

63 bottles of beer on the wall, 63 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 62 bottles of beer on the wall.

62 bottles of beer on the wall, 62 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 61 bottles of beer on the wall.

61 bottles of beer on the wall, 61 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 60 bottles of beer on the wall.

60 bottles of beer on the wall, 60 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 59 bottles of beer on the wall.

59 bottles of beer on the wall, 59 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 58 bottles of beer on the wall.

58 bottles of beer on the wall, 58 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 57 bottles of beer on the wall.

57 bottles of beer on the wall, 57 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 56 bottles of beer on the wall.

56 bottles of beer on the wall, 56 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 55 bottles of beer on the wall.

55 bottles of beer on the wall, 55 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 54 bottles of beer on the wall.

54 bottles of beer on the wall, 54 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 53 bottles of beer on the wall.

53 bottles of beer on the wall, 53 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 52 bottles of beer on the wall.

52 bottles of beer on the wall, 52 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 51 bottles of beer on the wall.

51 bottles of beer on the wall, 51 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 50 bottles of beer on the wall.

50 bottles of beer on the wall, 50 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 49 bottles of beer on the wall.

49 bottles of beer on the wall, 49 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 48 bottles of beer on the wall.

48 bottles of beer on the wall, 48 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 47 bottles of beer on the wall.

47 bottles of beer on the wall, 47 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 46 bottles of beer on the wall.

46 bottles of beer on the wall, 46 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 45 bottles of beer on the wall.

45 bottles of beer on the wall, 45 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 44 bottles of beer on the wall.

44 bottles of beer on the wall, 44 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 43 bottles of beer on the wall.

43 bottles of beer on the wall, 43 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 42 bottles of beer on the wall.

42 bottles of beer on the wall, 42 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 41 bottles of beer on the wall.

41 bottles of beer on the wall, 41 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 40 bottles of beer on the wall.

40 bottles of beer on the wall, 40 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 39 bottles of beer on the wall.

39 bottles of beer on the wall, 39 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 38 bottles of beer on the wall.

38 bottles of beer on the wall, 38 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 37 bottles of beer on the wall.

37 bottles of beer on the wall, 37 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 36 bottles of beer on the wall.

36 bottles of beer on the wall, 36 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 35 bottles of beer on the wall.

35 bottles of beer on the wall, 35 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 34 bottles of beer on the wall.

34 bottles of beer on the wall, 34 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 33 bottles of beer on the wall.

33 bottles of beer on the wall, 33 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 32 bottles of beer on the wall.

32 bottles of beer on the wall, 32 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 31 bottles of beer on the wall.

31 bottles of beer on the wall, 31 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 30 bottles of beer on the wall.

30 bottles of beer on the wall, 30 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 29 bottles of beer on the wall.

29 bottles of beer on the wall, 29 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 28 bottles of beer on the wall.

28 bottles of beer on the wall, 28 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 27 bottles of beer on the wall.

27 bottles of beer on the wall, 27 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 26 bottles of beer on the wall.

26 bottles of beer on the wall, 26 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 25 bottles of beer on the wall.

25 bottles of beer on the wall, 25 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 24 bottles of beer on the wall.

24 bottles of beer on the wall, 24 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 23 bottles of beer on the wall.

23 bottles of beer on the wall, 23 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 22 bottles of beer on the wall.

22 bottles of beer on the wall, 22 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 21 bottles of beer on the wall.

21 bottles of beer on the wall, 21 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 20 bottles of beer on the wall.

20 bottles of beer on the wall, 20 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 19 bottles of beer on the wall.

19 bottles of beer on the wall, 19 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 18 bottles of beer on the wall.

18 bottles of beer on the wall, 18 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 17 bottles of beer on the wall.

17 bottles of beer on the wall, 17 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 16 bottles of beer on the wall.

16 bottles of beer on the wall, 16 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 15 bottles of beer on the wall.

15 bottles of beer on the wall, 15 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 14 bottles of beer on the wall.

14 bottles of beer on the wall, 14 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 13 bottles of beer on the wall.

13 bottles of beer on the wall, 13 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 12 bottles of beer on the wall.

12 bottles of beer on the wall, 12 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 11 bottles of beer on the wall.

11 bottles of beer on the wall, 11 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 10 bottles of beer on the wall.

10 bottles of beer on the wall, 10 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 9 bottles of beer on the wall.

9 bottles of beer on the wall, 9 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 8 bottles of beer on the wall.

8 bottles of beer on the wall, 8 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 7 bottles of beer on the wall.

7 bottles of beer on the wall, 7 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 6 bottles of beer on the wall.

6 bottles of beer on the wall, 6 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 5 bottles of beer on the wall.

5 bottles of beer on the wall, 5 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 4 bottles of beer on the wall.

4 bottles of beer on the wall, 4 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 3 bottles of beer on the wall.

3 bottles of beer on the wall, 3 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 2 bottles of beer on the wall.

2 bottles of beer on the wall, 2 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 1 bottle of beer on the wall.

1 bottle of beer on the wall, 1 bottle of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, no more bottles of beer on the wall.

No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer. 
Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.`.split('\n').filter(Boolean)
```

Or, for this *particular* "song", which is very repetitive, you can create the lyrics yourself, which might have been the point of the exercise, though it's not very clear:

```js
const sing = () => [
  ...Array.from(
    { length: 98 },
    (_, i) => [
      `${99 - i} bottles of beer on the wall, ${99 - i} bottles of beer.`,
      `Take one down and pass it around, ${99 - i - 1} bottles of beer on the wall.`
    ]
  ).flat(),
  `1 bottle of beer on the wall, 1 bottle of beer.`,
  `Take one down and pass it around, no more bottles of beer on the wall.`,
  `No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer.`,
  `Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.`
];
const song = sing();
console.log(song[0] === '99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer.');
```

Comment: Doing this in my IDE `function splitLyrics (string) {
    return string.match(/\S[^.?!]*[.?!]/g);
}` seems to work in my terminal but not on codewars: https://www.codewars.com/kata/99-bottles-of-beer-1/train/javascript. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined`, which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't pass any parameter to `splitLyrics`, that's the only reason `string` would be `undefined`. Press "Run code snippet" in the answer - you'll see that the code indeed runs and the results are as desired

Comment: The function is set up in CodeWars not to take in a parameter, initially? https://i.imgur.com/cXHriJU.png, https://i.imgur.com/KNTqqvD.png

Comment: On the first line of your tests, you're invoking `sing` with no arguments with your `var song = sing()`, which means the first argument to `sing` is `undefined`. (I don't understand what that line is supposed to be doing either)

Comment: Right - I did not write that bit of code - that was just the default when I started working on the problem. The part that I wrote looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/cXHriJU.png

Comment: I tried pasting the code into the solution box on that site, but it keeps saying `Server Execution Error:
Missing language
Request Error:
Request failed with status code 422` even after I've tried to select "Javascript" multiple times. I think the site has a few bugs.

Comment: If `var song = sing();` is required, and the tester proceeds to call `song`, then you should write a function that *returns* a function, though this seems like a very odd thing to do. `const sing = () => str => str.match(/\S[^.]*\./g);`, see edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192190/discussion-between-happyhands31-and-certainperformance).

Answer (score 2):

use the split function :).

```
string.split(". ");
```

You can combine it with trim(), which removes whitespace around characters (only beginning and end of string) like this:

```
const stringArray = string
  .split(".")
  .map(str => str.trim())
```

Every string is first split on '.', and then each string is trimmed.
This should make the code more robust for weird whitespace issues.

If you need more options, I recommend match/regexp :)

Comment: Oh wow - so easy! I didn't realize you could split a string by certain punctuation like that. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, `split` will remove the trailing `.` from the sentences.

Comment: Yeah, user2340824 is right. split is the 'first goto' for string -> array, but if you need more options, check out regexp matching (other answer :) )

Comment: Hmm my console does not like that `.trim()` at the end of it....`TypeError: string.split(...).trim is not a function`