# Split text and wrap it in the span element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to take the sentence inside the tag that looks like this:

```
<p>Hello world. Lorem ipsum lorem.</p>
```

And transform it in this via JS/jQuery:

```
<p><span>Hello world.</span> Lorem ipsum lorem.</p>
```

Only thing that comes to my mind is the wrapAll() method, but how could I be sure that I can select the correct text - so the first part including the dot (Hello world.) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select first 2 words with jQuery and wrap them with <span> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182113/select-first-2-words-with-jquery-and-wrap-them-with-span-tag)

Comment: There is no need to `split` or `wrapAll()` see the duplicate above. just use replace with a simple `regex`

Comment: thank, partially - I would like to wrap everything before the dot, including the dot. So 2-3 or n number of words

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split String Into Array Elements Based On Punctuation In String - JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55787514/split-string-into-array-elements-based-on-punctuation-in-string-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a simple JS script:

```
let el = document.querySelect('...')
let str = el.innerText;
let indx = str.indexOf('.',0) + 1;
el.innerText = "<span>${str.substr(0,indx)}</span>${str.substr(indx)}"
```

Comment: thanks, this looks good, it just prints the span tag directly into the view. I am trying to escape it somehow

Answer (score 1):

You should be more specific: what exactly do you want to wrap in span? The part of the paragraph to the first period?

If so, you you have to check the index of the first period:

```
const ParagraphHTML = $('p#yourParagraph').html();
const PeriodIndex = ParagraphHTML.indexOf('.');
```

Then, you can slice your string into two parts, and join them with span:

```
const String1 = ParagraphHTML.slice(0,PeriodIndex+1);
const String2 = ParagraphHTML.slice(PeriodIndex+1);
const ResultString = `<span>${String1}</span>${String2}`;
$('p#yourParagraph').html(ResultString);
```

*I used jQuery, as you mentioned in the post. More variables than needed, are used for better readbility.*